# Need help trying to trap & change a field lable

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, metadata

Folks-
Okay, so upfront...I am barely literate in PHP.

I have a Wordpress template that I am trying to modify. It displays a member list. For each member, it displays a list of meta field values. Here is the original code:

```
<?php foreach ( $reveal_fields as $key ) { ?>
   <# if ( typeof user['<?php echo $key; ?>'] !== 'undefined' ) { #>
    <span class="label">{{{user['label_<?php echo $key;?>']}}}:</span> {{{user['<?php echo $key;?>']}}}<br />
   <# } #>
<?php } ?>
```

It works fine. The only thing that I want to change is that the label for the user_email field is "E-mail Address: and I want it to use "Email" instead. Rather than trying to change the label at its source (which is somewhere in the WP core code, I hope to catch the field within the loop using an if...else.. and substitute the text.

here's what I tried:

```
<?php foreach ( $reveal_fields as $key ) { ?>

    <# if ( typeof user['<?php echo $key; ?>'] !== 'undefined' ) { #>
        <span class="label">
<?php if ($key != 'user_email') {
            {{{user['label_<?php echo $key;?>']}}}
}else{
            echo 'Email'
} ?>:
        </span> {{{user['<?php echo $key;?>']}}}<br />
    <# } #>

<?php } ?>
```

Not only didn't it work, it produced a critical error. I'm just not fluent-enough to troubleshoot this! I'm hoping someone here can help me.

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: It looks like the issue is with the syntax of your if...else statement inside the loop. You have mixed up the PHP and JavaScript syntax, which is causing a syntax error.  https://goonlinetools.com/snapshot/code/#xiths9633j9f242gatbc

Comment: @Uncle Iroh
 That could very well be...I'm not seeing the error. Is it the != --should it be !== ?  Is it the three braces {{{ }}} ? Is it that I need spaces on either side of the else?

Comment: The PHP code is creating code to be used by the underscore templating language. But you can't just mix the two like this. `{{{user['label_<?php echo $key;?>']}}}` is not PHP syntax, you need to output this as text, same as you did with the `Email` in the else-branch. So either echo it, or use `?> ... <?php` to place this text outside of the PHP.

Comment: @CBroe - Thanks for the help... that was enough to help me figure it out!